# Deshabilitar un botón durante 5 minutos

Tags: javascript, angular

Me pueden ayudar a deshabilitar un boton durante 5 minutos, tengo este codigo que si lo hace, pero si recargo la pagina inicia a contar desde cero y no guarda el tiempo que ya se lleva contado.

```js
function confirmEnviar() {
  miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = true; 
  miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Deshabilitado...";
  setTimeout(function(){
    miformulario.btnEnviar.disabled = false;
    miformulario.btnEnviar.value = "Habilitado";
  }, 300000);
  return false;
}

miformulario.btnEnviar.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    return confirmEnviar();
}, false);
```

```html
<form name="miformulario">
  <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" value="Habilitado" />
</form>
```

Comment: Cuando actualizas la página, se reinician las funciones que están en proceso. Lo podrías hacer con el localstorage, ya que el valor que almacenas ahí, se permanecerá a pesar de que refresques la página.

Comment: Si estás interesado en más seguridad, la comprobación del tiempo debería suceder en el backend, ya que todo lo que esté en el navegador del usuario puede ser alterado.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías guardar la fecha en una variable en el localStorage, usando una condicional para revisar si nunca ha sido guardada, y ya que la hayas guardado, sólo haces un conteo de qué tantos segundos han pasado entre esa primera fecha, y la fecha en la que quieres revisar si ya pasaron los 5 minutos (300 segundos), algo como esto

```js
if(!localStorage.getItem('firstDate')){
    var firstDate = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem('firstDate', firstDate);
}
var b = new Date();
let firstDateComparator = new Date(localStorage.getItem('firstDate'))
var difference = (b - firstDateComparator) / 1000;

console.log(difference + " seconds");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que recargues javascript se reiniciarán los valores que estén guardados en el código por lo tanto tienes que guardar el momento de inicio en algún sitio.

La mejor opción es ayudarte del local storage. Es como una pequeña base de datos que tiene el navegador y desde javascript es muy facil utilizarla. Cuando inicies tu código pregunta por la variable que crees, si no existe empieza a contar desde 0 y guarda el momento en el que empezaste a contar en la variable del local storage. La próxima vez que recargues el javascript y tu código pregunte por la variable ya si existirá y solo tienes que hacer que empiece a contar teniendo en cuenta cuando se empezó.

;)